# Sort products by date DESC as the base sort order on category page?

Tags: sort

For example, below products are created in sequential order:

```
A - oldest, added 5 months ago
B
C
D
E
F - newest, added today
```

Magento's default sort order seems to be by Date ASC with the oldest products at the top:

```
A - oldest
B
C
D
E
F - newest
```

However if "Default Product Listing Sort By" of this category is selected as "Best Value" in Catalog > Manage Categories > (Choose the category) > Display Settings, AND some of the products are given arbitrary "Position" values other than the default value 1 in "Category Products" tab, the category product listing sort order would be like this:

```
E - pos = 112
C - pos = 27
A - pos = 1, oldest
B - pos = 1
D - pos = 1
F - pos = 1, newest
```

Basically, you can either sort them by Date or by Position, but NOT both at the same time. I can set order by Date DESC as the category default sorting but then position sorting will not work.

So my question is this. How can I sort the products first by date DESC, and then by Position DESC? So the product listing of a particular category looks like this:

```
E - pos = 112
C - pos = 27
F - pos = 1, newest
D - pos = 1
B - pos = 1
A - pos = 1, oldest
```

Which is much more desirable as immediately after position sorting, newer products come ahead of older products.

How can I sort the product listing on category pages by Date DESC rather than by Date ASC as the base sort order? So the other sort types work on top of that?

Please let me know if I made myself clear.